# Outlook API to forward email as attachment

Tags: office-js, outlook-restapi

I'm currently developing an Outlook Add-in and trying to add a feature to forward an email as an attachment.

Can anyone please advice what the simplest way to accomplish it? I cannot find a single API to do it in [Outlook Mail REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations).

Is there any easier way instead of using the 3 different APIs?

1. [CreateForwardDraft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#CreateForwardDraft)
2. [UpdateMessages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#UpdateMessages)
3. [SendDraftMessages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#SendDraftMessages)

Comment: Could you clarify, are you building an Outlook Web Add-in or a VSTO/COM based Outlook Add-in? I ask due to your choice of the Outlook REST API. This isn't an obvious choice for Office.js since it has support for calling EWS and Microsoft Graph baked-in but not Outlook REST API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an API - [`addItemAttachmentAsync`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook#additemattachmentasyncitemid-attachmentname-options-callback) which can add an email as an attachment.

Currently, the forward functionality you requested is not a part of the product. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: problem with that is it doesnt include  any attachments from the original message.

Comment: How do I attach the item as an attachment to a draft item ?